# How to add class to an image_tag rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, helper, lccs

I have the following code:

```
<%= image_tag iterator.image.url(:small), :class => "img_preview" %>
```

But the rendered HTML shows:

```
<img src="/actives/hotels/13/small/clean_wave.jpg?1317675452" alt="Clean_wave">
```

Why the "class" attribute isn't there?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe because of your parentheses around (:small)... Try image_tag(iterator.image.url(:small), :class => "img_preview") (with parentheses all around)

Comment: Noup.... that didn't work either =S

Comment: I use in this way, here works.
`<%= image_tag 'delete.png', :class => "ajax-delete" %>`
`<img src="/images/delete.png?1322020304" class="ajax-delete" alt="Delete">`

Comment: The way you have it should work... Something else must be going on. Can you post the rest of your view code? Do you have javascript affecting this view that could be at fault?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Your class has to be assigned inside of the brackets to be used as part of the options being passed through. Try:

```
<%= image_tag(iterator.image.url(:small), :class => "img_preview") %>
```

Comment: This way you're passing the `:class` option to the `url` method, which is very unlikely to work (why would the `url` method have any knowledge of what HTML tag it's being used in?). I have a feeling what you really meant was `image_tag(iterator.image.url(:small), :class => "img_preview")`.

Answer (score 17):

For newbies like myself, heres a cleaner version with the newer rails syntax:

```
<%= image_tag iterator.image.url(:small), class:"img_preview" %>
```

Comment: The accepted code works, but this is cleaner.  Thanks!

Comment: To be nitpicky, there should be a space between `class` and `"img_preview"`. Also, this syntax is from Ruby 1.9+, and it's not specific to Rails (just Ruby itself). But yes, this is nicer :)